# Select any radio button on a page

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onchange

I have two radio groups and i need to get value of any radio button on change. but jQuery only return value of first group radio item when clicked on second group.

Thank you for your suggestions to add :radio to the .options selector but I have other form elements like select which i monitor change to. Any way we can add this in variable ?

```js
$('.options').change(function() {           
        
        var checkedInput = $('.options input:checked').val(); 
        
        console.log('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);    
         alert('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);    
       
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="options">
 
  <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="pink" checked >
  <label for=""> pink </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="blue">
  <label for=""> blue </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="black">
  <label for=""> black </label>
  <hr>
  
  <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="orange">
  <label for=""> orange </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="banana">
  <label for=""> banana </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="apple">
  <label for=""> apple </label>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Close just that there is only one div with .options class and all form elements are inside it. and I want only the value of radio buttons in one var.

```js
$(function () {
  var eleToSelect = '.options :radio';
  $(eleToSelect).change(function() {

    var checkedInput = $(this).val();

    console.log('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);

    alert('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);
    $('#result').text('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);  // for the snippet

  });
  eleToSelect = '.options1 select';
  $(eleToSelect).change(function() {

    var checkedInput = $(this).val();

    console.log('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);

    alert('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);
    $('#result').text('Checked input is : '+ checkedInput);  // for the snippet

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="options">

    <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="pink" checked >
    <label for=""> pink </label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="blue">
    <label for=""> blue </label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-one" value="black">
    <label for=""> black </label>
    <hr>

    <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="orange">
    <label for=""> orange </label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="banana">
    <label for=""> banana </label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-two" value="apple">
    <label for=""> apple </label>
<br>

    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @gaemaf Thank you for your suggestions to add :radio to the .options selector but I have other form elements like select which i monitor change to. Any way we can add this in variable ?

Comment: @VinayKashyap I updated the snippet hoping I have understood what you asked. If it's all ok can you accept and upvote?